# gdb: No symbol "tulip" in current context

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm trying to compile my program and make it executable, but every time I try to print it says: "No symbol "tulip" in current context.
"

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
unsigned long *daffodil = (unsigned long *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
if (daffodil == (unsigned long *) NULL)
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
*daffodil = 170;
unsigned long *tulip = daffodil;
unsigned long *carnation = (unsigned long *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
if (carnation == (unsigned long *) NULL)
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
*carnation = 995;
unsigned long *lily = tulip;
unsigned long crocus = 953;
unsigned long *zinnia = &crocus;
(void) printf("Registering daffodil: %lu.\n", *daffodil);
(void) printf("Registering tulip: %lu.\n", *tulip);
(void) printf("Registering carnation: %lu.\n",*carnation);
(void) printf("Registering lily: %lu.\n", *lily);
(void) printf("Registering crocus: %lu.\n", crocus);
(void) printf("Registering zinnia: %lu.\n", *zinnia);
carnation = (unsigned long *) NULL;
free(daffodil);
free(carnation);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is what I do in the terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see local variables in GDB you have to break the program execution inside that function. You are trying to print the value after the program has terminated and that is impossible.

Try putting a breakpoint at line 10, I think:

```
(gdb) br 10
(gdb) run
(gdb) print tulip
```

You could also break at the start of `main` and then advance until the variable is initialized:

```
(gdb) br main
(gdb) run
(gdb) next
(gdb) next
(gdb) ...
(gdb) print tulip
```

The breakpoint at `main` is so frequent that `gdb` has a command that does that automatically: `start`.

If you are particularly interested in a variable, then you can *display* it, so that it will be printed automatically at every step:

```
(gdb) start
(gdb) display tulip
(gdb) next
(gdb) next
(gdb) ...
```

Comment: It works :) But when I write `ptype *tulip` it should write `type = long unsigned int` but it just writes `type = long unsigned`

Comment: @hudhud: `long unsigned` and `long unsigned int` are the same type. As are `unsigned` and `unsigned int`. Or `long` and `long int`. With these types, the `int` is redundant and often ommited, except for plain `int` that in modern C cannot be ommitted.